# Non-invasive way to group together declaration blocks in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In my project, I have several generally entirely separate elements on the same page, that would ideally share the same CSS file (as they currently do). At the moment, I have a lot of repeated child selectors (e.g. `section.a >`) and it would be nice if similar selectors could be grouped into one big IDE-collapsible chunk. I did some investigation and found `@layer`, which I did use to  some extent:

```css
@layer a {
     section.a > foo {
     }
     section.a > bar {
     }
}

@layer b {
     section.b > foo {
     }
     section.b > bar {
     }
}
```

However, unfortunately, I found out that it has some undesired behavior with inheritance that would be hard to reconcile at this point, and so only a few groups get `@layer`s. I was wondering if there was something similar that did not have any specific implications on the declarations within.

Thanks for any and all answers! (No, "use multiple files" is not an answer, I want to have my cake and eat it too)

Comment: Then, no, it does not exist at the moment. Perhaps an always matching media query? `@media all and (min-width:0){}` or something? Or you can hold out a little for nested selectors - we're almost there with those, support is getting there. Though you shouldn't write CSS for your IDE, because every step you add adds processing steps on your client side - regardless of how useless it is, it eats _some_ cycles.